# Making Objects Appear on Click

Tags: java, gobject

I am very new to Java programming. I am currently trying to make a game where white balls keep appearing on the screen and the user has to click and drag the ball off onto the right side of the canvas to make it disappear. I am not finished writing the code, but the code I do have keeps crashing my Java program. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code I have and why my program keeps crashing? Thank you!

```
public class BubbleGame extends GraphicsProgram
{

//~ Instance/static variables


private GRect field;
private GRect goal;
private GObject gobj;           /* The object being dragged */
private GPoint last;            /* The last mouse position  */

private RandomGenerator rgen = new RandomGenerator();

//~ Constructor ...........................................................

// ----------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Creates a new BubbleGame object.
 */
public void init()
{
    //call method to create regions
    CreateRegions();

    //add mouse listeners
    addMouseListeners();

    //loop to add bubbles
    while (true)
    {
        //create a filled bubble
        GOval oval = new GOval (100, 100, 50, 50);
        oval.setFilled(true);
        oval.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        add(oval);

        //randomly generate coordinates within the field


        //add the bubble and pause 



    }
}


//~ Methods ...............................................................
public void CreateRegions(){

     //create and add the field with the size and color of your choice
     field = new GRect(0, 0, getWidth() * .75, getHeight());
     field.setFilled(true);
     field.setColor(Color.GREEN);
     add(field);

     //create and add the adjacent goal with the size and color of your choice
     goal = new GRect(493, 0, getWidth() * .25, getHeight());
     goal.setFilled(true);
     goal.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     add(goal);
    }



/* Called on mouse press to record the coordinates of the click */
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    last = new GPoint(e.getPoint());
    gobj = getElementAt(last);
    //later add check that not dragging field or goal

}

/* Called on mouse drag to reposition the object */
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if (gobj != null) {
        gobj.move(e.getX() - last.getX(), e.getY() - last.getY());
        last = new GPoint(e.getPoint());
    }    

}

/* Called on mouse drag to reposition the object */
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    //if gobj has a value and its coordinates are contained by goal, make it invisible  




}


}
```

Comment: "It's crashing" doesn't help at all you know. What's the error message?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your while loop is the reason it crashes. You may consider putting a sleep here, so that your application will not use cpu constantly:

```
    while (true)
    {
        //create a filled bubble
        GOval oval = new GOval (100, 100, 50, 50);
        oval.setFilled(true);
        oval.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        add(oval);

        //randomly generate coordinates within the field


        //add the bubble and pause 


        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
```

Also you are adding GOval objects constantly. I do not know about GraphicsProgram class, but it may also cause your memory to fill up at some point.

Answer (score 0):

By doing the following you are drawing a circle at a specific location.

```
GOval oval = new GOval (100, 100, 50, 50);
```

But `while (true)` will re-execute this code immediately after it has finished, and keep on doing this forever. This will fill up your memory and eventually cause a crash.

But besides that, it is pointless as the user wouldn't even see separate circles: they are drawn on top of each other.

If that is indeed what you are looking for, then I would suggest adding an `Integer` that counts the number of circles currently in the screen. You would then add to the end of your current `While`-loop:

```
while(counter > 2 ) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

This will keep exactly two circles in the canvas at all times, with a maximum delay of ~100 ms.

Your IDE will remind you of the exceptions you should probably catch.

What might make more sense both programatically and functionally, is either:

- Adding the code to draw a new circle to the event of an old circle being deleted, and draw only one circle at program initialisation. Or,
- Changing the `While`-loop to a `For`-loop, which for example runs maybe 10 times. Then add code to randomise the position of each circle.

`Random randomGenerator = new Random();`

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    int pos1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);  // random between 0 and 99
    int pos2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);  // random between 0 and 99
    int pos3 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);  // random between 0 and 99
    int pos4 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);  // random between 0 and 99
    GOval oval = new GOval (pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your GOval out of the while loop. Keeping it in there is making it regenerate therefore crashing.